# Mathematical logic material for blind student

Tags: logic, reference-request

A friend of mine (trained in philosophy and history) has recently become interested in mathematical logic. Because he is effectively blind, he has a hard time coping with formalism, as it does not translate well intro Braille. I was hoping to recommend him Chiswell and Hodge's *Mathematical Logic* as an entry point, but without some translation tool into Braille, this seems quite impenetrable to him. Does anybody have some experience how to deal with this issue?

I am grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. But I heartily wish your friend good luck. It should be really tough to study logic without drawing diagrams or writing formulas. I admire him/her.

Comment: A few (perhaps) related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737055/math-for-blind-people, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35496/is-there-a-definitive-guide-to-speaking-mathematics, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894433/learning-math-while-visually-impaired

Answer (score 3):

There are various centers for students with disabilities. The best way could be to ask there. They have convenient materials or at least know, which center has such materials.

Does your friend know **Nemeth code**? 
I hope this link can help http://www.gh-mathspeak.com/examples/NemethBook/index.php?verbosity=v&explicitness=2&interp=1&voice=William&lang=en&braille=ascii&images=display&rule=20

Please try and give us feed-back in few days.
Good luck!